# Make a custom field as a range - like "Price" is as default in Bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Hi I am new in Bigcommerce can I make any  custom field or field as a Range and filter data base on that range.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what functionality you're needing from this custom field, you may be able to use it for the 'price range'. The value type is string, so this does not accept an array of multiple values, you can see this in our [API reference documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store-management/catalog/product-custom-fields/createcustomfield). If you're just needing to use custom fields to render the text on a template or so, this could work, but if you're needing more functionality from it, it'd be best to use something else.